# IIS: SSL certificate request and private key exportable

Tags: iis, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm writing to ask for this question: when a new wildcard SSL certificate request is made from IIS (wizard), does the "private key exportable" option enabled ? Because once installed, I need to export the new certificate together with private key.

Thank you,
Luca

Answer (score 0):

If you need to export the key (to install the same cert in other server for example) you need to mark private Key as exportable. Otherwise that certificate wont work in any other machine (as the key will be different) I do not think its a best practise tho.

Comment: Hello Alexander,
thank you for your feedback.
I understand/know a private key should be marked as exportable, otherwise I cannot export it and re-use it in other systems; but when a new CSR is generated from IIS (through the wizard) there is no way to mark the private key as exportable, so can I assume it marked as exportable "in background" ?

Comment: You can use MMC (type it on a cmd) and then open certificates. If you request it from there you can mark the key as exportable.

Answer (score 0):

I found a more secure way:

1. Generate the CSR and private key file by using openssl
2. Submit the CSR to public CA
3. Convert the certificate issued by public CA from CRT to PFX (containing the private key - not marked as exportable)

Bye,
Luca